# Displaying "open" or "closed" based on current Date/Time excluding Saturday and Sunday PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to display an "open" or "closed" graphic on a PHP page if the current date/time is between the stores opening times:

```
$mycurrentdateandtime = new DateTime();

$open = new DateTime( $mycurrentdateandtime->format('Y-m-d').' 09:30');
$close = new DateTime($mycurrentdateandtime->format('Y-m-d').' 17:00');

if (($mycurrentdateandtime >= $open) && ($mycurrentdateandtime <= $close)) {
    echo 'yes we are open';
} else {
    echo 'sorry we are closed';
}
```

I'm not great at PHP but the above works fine however I'd like to display "sorry we are closed" if it's either a Saturday or a Sunday.  How can I edit the above code to check that?

Thank you.
NJ

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $mycurrentdateandtime = new DateTime();

    $open = new DateTime( $mycurrentdateandtime->format('Y-m-d').' 09:30');
    $close = new DateTime($mycurrentdateandtime->format('Y-m-d').' 17:00');

    if (($mycurrentdateandtime >= $open) && ($mycurrentdateandtime <= $close) && ($open->format('N') != 6) && ($open->format('N') !=7)) {
        echo 'yes we are open';
    } else {
        echo 'sorry we are closed';
    }
```

[PHP Manual: DateTime::Format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

I added a check to see if the DateTime formatted to 'N' (Numeric representation of the day 1-7, 1 meaning Monday and 7 meaning Sunday) did not equal 6 (Saturday) or 7 (Sunday).

Comment: Thank you bnahin. Easy when you know how.